# Maven Struts2 project (org.apache.struts:struts2-archetype-starter) created with some issues in intellij idea 15.0.4

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, struts2

I created Struts2 project in IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4(ultimate edition) using maven3 (chose `org.apache.struts:struts2-archetype-starter`). After creating this project there're some issues like on screens below. I want to notice that I enabled auto-import for maven.

[image]
[image]

Here's my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>dadas</groupId>
    <artifactId>adasd</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>adasd</name>
    <description>Struts 2 Starter</description>


      <properties>
        <struts2.version>2.5-BETA3</struts2.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--  Struts 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-sitemesh-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-config-browser-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet & Jsp -->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Jakarta Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dwr -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.ltd.getahead</groupId>
            <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-beta-3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <finalName>struts2-archetype-starter</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                   <source>1.5</source>
                   <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.7.v20120910</version>
                <configuration>
                    <stopKey>CTRL+C</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>8999</stopPort>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>log4j.configuration</name>
                            <value>file:${basedir}/src/main/resources/log4j.properties</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>slf4j</name>
                            <value>false</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/adasd</contextPath>
                        <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</descriptor>
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.17</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Obviously you're missing dependencies. Unrelated, but post text, not images.

Comment: @DaveNewton you can see my pom.xml. I haven't changed anything in this file since projects was created. Auto-import for maven is enabled.

Comment: Regardless of the pom file the artifacts aren't being deployed or included.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `pom.xml` and add

```xml
<properties>
    <struts2.version>2.3.24.1</struts2.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>${struts2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

The compilation error points to the missing dependencies in the project configuration. If you are using Maven with IJ you should synchronize Maven configuration with IJ configuration. To let IJ do it automatically you can check box on the notification shown or use project settings.

Comment: There're some dependencies such as you wrote above. You can see my whole pom.xml above.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem. You have to change data in tag `<version>` in pom.xml. As shows below.

```
<!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

to

`<!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: or put         `<log4j2.version>2.5</log4j2.version>` :)